# Do SASS maps have an option to set common values for all keys?

Tags: css, sass

I have a SASS map which has some repetitive values for all keys:

```
$test-h1:(
  null: (
    font-size: 20px,
    color: red,
    font-weight: 100
  ),
  small:(
    font-size: 30px,
    color: yellow,
    font-weight: 100
  ),
  medium:(
    font-size: 40,
    color: orange,
    font-weight: 100
  ),
  large:(
    font-size: 50px,
    color: green,
    font-weight: 100
  )
);
```

Is there a way that I can extract the common values and inherit them for all keys? Or would I have to do it using the repetitive method only or use another key called `common` and add it to all the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sass does not have any such feature.  You have to programatically alter the mapping itself using map-merge.

```
$test-h1:(
  null: (
    font-size: 20px,
    color: red
  ),
  small:(
    font-size: 30px,
    color: yellow
  ),
  medium:(
    font-size: 40,
    color: orange
  ),
  large:(
    font-size: 50px,
    color: green
  )
);

$common:
    (font-weight: 100);

@each $k, $v in $test-h1 {
  $test-h1: map-merge($test-h1, ($k: map-merge($v, $common)));
}
```